# Google Charts - Responsive Issue - Dynamically Resize

Tags: javascript, html, responsive, google-visualization

I am trying to make my Google Column Material Chart responsive, but it seems a bit choppy to me and doesnt work well at all. Can anyone help me make this flow well

The chart will only appear in that format when the page is loaded. It won’t dynamically resize when the browser window width is changed.

JSFIDDLE
https://jsfiddle.net/rbla/Le8g0sw0/8/

HTML

```
<div id="chart">
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#chart {
   border:5px solid #AAA;
   width: 80%; 
   min-height: 450px;
}
```

JS

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script>

  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
      ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
      ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
      ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
      ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
    ]);

    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
      },
      bars: 'vertical',
      vAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
      height: 400,
      colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02', '#7570b3']
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));



  }

     // REFLOW
    $(window).resize(function(){
        drawChart();
    });
```

Comment: I have changed the width to 100% - but it doesnt reflow when I resize it - works fine when I RUN this, but not when I resize

Answer (score 5):

in the fiddle, you are using JQuery to listen for window resize...

```
    $(window).resize(function(){
        drawChart();
    });
```

however, JQuery is not included...

use `addEventListener` instead, or include a reference to JQuery,
see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['bar']
}).then(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
    ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
    ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
    ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
    ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
    },
    bars: 'vertical',
    vAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
    height: 400,
    colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02', '#7570b3']
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
}
```

```css
#chart {
  border: 5px solid #AAA;
  min-height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart">
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the width from 80% to 100% like this example:

```
#chart {
    border: 5px solid #AAA;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 450px;
}
```