# How to scale stacked google chart for mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization, responsive

I have a stacked chart which is responsive for most screen sizes based on the solution for responsiveness provided here: [Google Charts - Responsive Issue - Dynamically Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334143/google-charts-responsive-issue-dynamically-resize)

The problem is that despite none of the data values being higher than 5000, when viewed on mobile the scale goes up to 10,000 and the entire chart is rendered illegible. How can i scale the chart correctly for mobile?

JSFIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/385rzhsg

[image: chart rendered in portrait mode on mobile]

HTML

```
    <div id="chart"><div id="soc_chart"></div></div>
```

CSS

```
#chart {
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  min-height: 1000px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStacked);

function drawStacked() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['SOC', 'GEEKBENCH 5 SINGLE', 'GEEKBENCH 5 MULTI'],
        ['SNAPDRAGON 870', 914, 3161],
        ['MEDIATEK DIMENSITY 900 (MT6877)', 731, 2203],
        ['SNAPDRAGON 845', 504, 2028],
        ['MEDIATEK DIMENSITY 700 (MT6833V)', 544, 1695],
        ['MEDIATEK G95', 501, 1599],
        ['UNISOC TIGER T618', 392, 1441],
        ['UNISOC TIGER T310', 360, 708],
        ['MEDIATEK MT8176', 314, 644],
        ['MEDIATEK HELIO P60 (MT6771)', 288, 1272],
        ['ROCKCHIP RK3399', 269, 615],
        ['BROADCOM BCM2711', 234, 672],
        ['ROCKCHIP RK3326', 86, 272],
        ['MEDIATEK MT6580A', 69, 227],
        ['ROCKCHIP RK3288', 10, 20]
]);


      var options = {
        chartArea: {'width': 'auto', 'height': '90%'},
        legend: 
            {'position':'top', 
            textStyle: {color: 'black', fontName: 'Lato', fontSize: 14, bold: true, italic: false}},
        height: 1000,
        isStacked: true,
        hAxis: 
            {title: 'GEEKBENCH 5 SCORE', 
            textStyle: {color: 'black', fontName: 'Lato', fontSize: 12, bold: true, italic: false}, 
            titleTextStyle: {color: '#940000', fontName: 'Lato', bold: true, italic: false}}, 
        series: {
            0:{color:'#F75200'},
            1:{color:'#940000'}},
        vAxis: 
            {title: 'SOC NAME', 
            textStyle: {color: 'black', fontName: 'Lato', fontSize: 12, bold: true, italic: false},
            titleTextStyle: {color: '#940000', fontName: 'Lato', bold: true, italic: false}}
       };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('soc_chart'));
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
        window.addEventListener('resize', drawStacked, false);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for starters, let's take a look at the options for the chart.

```
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('soc_chart'));
chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
```

the `convertOptions` method is used to convert options for *classic* charts to *material* charts.
but the chart being drawn is a classic chart, so there is no need to use `convertOptions`.

classic chart: `google.visualization.BarChart`
material chart: `google.charts.Bar`

try removing the method...

```
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('soc_chart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

also, the `'bar'` package is for loading *material* charts,
so it isn't needed either.

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
```

change to...

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
```

if after these changes, the axis continues to extend beyond the max value,
you can manually set the axis range.

we can find the max value of the row stacks, then round up to the nearest 1000.

```
  var maxStack = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    var rowStack = data.getValue(i, 1) + data.getValue(i, 2);
    maxStack = maxStack || rowStack;
    maxStack = Math.max(maxStack, rowStack);
  }
  var maxRound = Math.ceil(maxStack / 1000) * 1000;
```

then use that value to set the max value of the axis.

```
    hAxis: {
      title: 'GEEKBENCH 5 SCORE',
      textStyle: {color: 'black', fontName: 'Lato', fontSize: 12, bold: true, italic: false},
      titleTextStyle: {color: '#940000', fontName: 'Lato', bold: true, italic: false},
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: maxRound  // set max value of axis
      }
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['SOC', 'GEEKBENCH 5 SINGLE', 'GEEKBENCH 5 MULTI'],
    ['SNAPDRAGON 870', 914, 3161],
    ['MEDIATEK DIMENSITY 900 (MT6877)', 731, 2203],
    ['SNAPDRAGON 845', 504, 2028],
    ['MEDIATEK DIMENSITY 700 (MT6833V)', 544, 1695],
    ['MEDIATEK G95', 501, 1599],
    ['UNISOC TIGER T618', 392, 1441],
    ['UNISOC TIGER T310', 360, 708],
    ['MEDIATEK MT8176', 314, 644],
    ['MEDIATEK HELIO P60 (MT6771)', 288, 1272],
    ['ROCKCHIP RK3399', 269, 615],
    ['BROADCOM BCM2711', 234, 672],
    ['ROCKCHIP RK3326', 86, 272],
    ['MEDIATEK MT6580A', 69, 227],
    ['ROCKCHIP RK3288', 10, 20]
  ]);
  
  var maxStack = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    var rowStack = data.getValue(i, 1) + data.getValue(i, 2);
    maxStack = maxStack || rowStack;
    maxStack = Math.max(maxStack, rowStack);
  }
  var maxRound = Math.ceil(maxStack / 1000) * 1000;

  var options = {
    chartArea: {'width': 'auto', 'height': '90%'},
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
      textStyle: {color: 'black', fontName: 'Lato', fontSize: 14, bold: true, italic: false}
    },
    height: 1000,
    isStacked: true,
    hAxis: {
      title: 'GEEKBENCH 5 SCORE',
      textStyle: {color: 'black', fontName: 'Lato', fontSize: 12, bold: true, italic: false},
      titleTextStyle: {color: '#940000', fontName: 'Lato', bold: true, italic: false},
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: maxRound
      }
    },
    series: {
      0:{color:'#F75200'},
      1:{color:'#940000'}
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'SOC NAME',
      textStyle: {color: 'black', fontName: 'Lato', fontSize: 12, bold: true, italic: false},
      titleTextStyle: {color: '#940000', fontName: 'Lato', bold: true, italic: false}
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('soc_chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="soc_chart"></div>
```

Comment: thanks so much for the explanation, it all makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: it looks like the horizontal scale doesn't correlate with the values for the bars now. for example the max value is over 3000, but the scale only hits 3000 max.

Comment: thanks, changed answer above, 2 things. I didn't consider that the bars are stacked, so need to find the max value of the combined series. and instead of rounding to the nearest 1000 (`Math.round`), needed to round up to the nearest 1000 (`Math.ceil`)

Comment: thanks for the explanation, it still doesn't quite work though. i think what's happening is that the larger stack is not starting from zero, rather from the value at which the smaller stack ends. for example the top stack of 3161 looks like it is around 4075 on the haxis, which would be the sum of both stacks together.

Comment: yes, the top stack is 4075, which is found by the new routine above, then the max axis range is set to 5000 when rounding up to nearest 1000. but we can change how any of this works. which part exactly is not desirable? is 5000 too much?

Comment: it looks like this was an issue with my original code and i missed it. the problem with it is that the value of the largest stack is actually 3161: ['SNAPDRAGON 870', 914, 3161] but it lines up with the 4075 marker on the haxis. ideally the smaller stack should line up with 914 (which it does) and the larger stack should line up with 3161 rather than 4075 (the sum of both stacks). i really appreciate your time spent on this and i realise that this wasn't part of the original question.

Comment: always glad to help, when you use the `isStacked` option, the first series / bar will line up properly, 0 - 914. but then the second bar will start at 914 and add 3161, ending at 4075. if it should end at 3161, then you will need to adjust the data in the second series accordingly.

Comment: i must have misunderstood how stacked charts work, in that case thank you for your work on the scaling of the chart.