# How to redraw a Google visualization chart without re-passing the data?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to adjust a [Google Visualization Bar Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart) on events like the change of the window size.

The only way I seem to be able to accomplish this is with the `.draw` method and passing the chart data in again. This seems like a silly solution since the data didn't change, just the size of the window.

Trying to call `draw` with no data argument results in error `Data table is not defined`.

Is there no way to update the chart without essentially going through the same steps I do on creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

recommend using the [ChartWrapper Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapperobject)...

you can use the wrapper to create any chart,
assign the data and options upon creation,
and the `draw` method requires no arguments...

```
var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  chartType: 'BarChart',
  dataTable: data,
  options: chartOptions,
  containerId: 'chart_div'
});
wrapper.draw();
```

just be sure to include the `'controls'` package when loading...

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages:['controls', 'corechart']}).then(function () {...
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to cobble together something with the Wrapper using `setDataTable` and `setOption` (for width and height changes) so that now I can resize without concern for data, but also still update the underlying data when needed. Was surprisingly hard to accomplish both those together.

Comment: cheers! not sure i follow the size issue but you should be able to make the chart responsive to the container size without changing size options, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49178724/5090771)...

Comment: Had little luck with similar approaches. The chart is rendered in a "grid-stack" item that can be resized. Being explicit has so far worked well. I'll have to peruse some of your other answers in the category. Thanks again.