# Google Charts API - remove space on RHS?

Tags: html, google-visualization

I'm new to Google Charts so part of this problem might just be vocabulary. I don't know what to look for.

I have a **div** with a width of 250px and I've set up a chart to occupy the **div** with the following options:

```
    var options = {
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '100%',
        "curveType": 'function',
        legend: { position: 'none' },
        trendlines: { 0: {} }
    };
```

[image]

However, the chart that is rendered does not occupy the full width.
Specifically, the SVG node (returned by the API) has a width of 250 but the line chart has a block of blank space off to the right (outlined in red).  I'm guessing this might be for the 'minor' axis?

Experimenting, if I make the div or chart.options.width bigger than 250, the chart will overflow/hidden so and I'll miss the data on the right.

How do I control/eliminate this space?
It's a small chart and I want to occupy as much space as I can in the div with chart visual.

Just in case it matters, this is the call to draw the chart

```
    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chartQuick'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: check this answer --> [Google Chart too narrow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49178724/5090771)